# How can I use Go modules to pull a dependency by commit hash or branch?

Tags: go

I'm trying to upgrade my project to use Go modules for dependency management.  I recognize this a new/experimental feature.  I'm getting an error: `cannot find module providing package`.

My `go.mod` currently reads:

```
require (
    github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go v1.5.1
    github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo v0.19.0
    github.com/jonas747/dshardmanager v0.0.0-20180911185241-9e4282faed43
)
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD src/ /app

ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

# Building requires git because we're pulling a dependency by commit hash
RUN apk add --no-cache --update git \
    && go build ./... \
    && apk del git

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

When building, it fails with:

```
cannot load github.com/bugsnag/panicwrap: cannot find module providing package github.com/bugsnag/panicwrap
```

When I look at https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go I don't see a `go.mod` file.  Is this error indicating that this dependency doesn't support modules?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something wrong, because it works. It does not need a `go.mod` in order to work with `go.mod`-based applications:

```
nrxr at lise in ~/code/src/github.com/nrxr/stack
$ go mod init
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/nrxr/stack

nrxr at lise in ~/code/src/github.com/nrxr/stack
$ go get github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go
go: finding github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go v1.5.1
go: downloading github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go v1.5.1
go: extracting github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go v1.5.1
go: finding github.com/bugsnag/panicwrap v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/bugsnag/panicwrap v1.2.0
go: finding github.com/gofrs/uuid v3.2.0+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/gofrs/uuid v3.2.0+incompatible
go: extracting github.com/bugsnag/panicwrap v1.2.0
go: extracting github.com/gofrs/uuid v3.2.0+incompatible
go: finding github.com/kardianos/osext latest
go: downloading github.com/kardianos/osext v0.0.0-20190222173326-2bc1f35cddc0
go: extracting github.com/kardianos/osext v0.0.0-20190222173326-2bc1f35cddc0

nrxr at lise in ~/code/src/github.com/nrxr/stack
$ cat go.mod
module github.com/nrxr/stack

go 1.12

require (
        github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go v1.5.1 // indirect
        github.com/bugsnag/panicwrap v1.2.0 // indirect
        github.com/gofrs/uuid v3.2.0+incompatible // indirect
        github.com/kardianos/osext v0.0.0-20190222173326-2bc1f35cddc0 // indirect
)
```

Maybe try again? Try with what I just used here.

Comment: I didn't think `go get` was still necessary but dependencies were fetched as part of the build process...

Comment: Yes, you can ideally just `go mod init && go build` but I didn't had any actual code, hence my need for a `go get`.

Your error said it could not find a module providing panicwrap, get a go get for bugsnag-go did resolve it, so there was something else failing in your setup and the go get fixes it.

Comment: Oh, actually, you don't have `GO111MODULE=on` set in your `Dockerfile`. Anyway, the recommended setup in the `Dockerfile` is something like:
```
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . ./
```

This way you can actually cache the vendored libraries.